# External content (images) on website optimize load

Tags: php, html

I am using an API XML service for a B2B Hotel Booking.
I have the list of Hotel images provided by them. At this time the images are stored on their server,

But sometimes their server becomes overloaded i dont know exactely and my website loads very slow when arrives at images.

Is there a way to store those images on my website if i have the images urls or how can i optimize the loading speed to be not affected by their overload.

Answer (score 0):

i know your only tag is html, but i would suggest you run a php script that uses curl to actually GET the files and to store them.

Comment: its not a bad ideea. I will start research on how to build such code.

Comment: edited my post since i accidently put up a linux command, now there is a php function that does the trick